# Cycles black artifacts on transparent materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders, transparency, artifacts

so I am experimenting with Minecraft Grass models and I notice on the grass models that there are black artifacts when in rendered view. There are no overlapping faces or double vertices, but there is still artifacts. I would think that it was z fighting, but there are no overlaps. Anyone know how to fix this? Thank You! [image: Black Artifacts] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qvhlAMONyJKRXgJZq1TZjSi_ydmUSrv4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's going to be the really tricky (or tedious) part - it seems that each of the "grass plane bundles" have 2 duplicate faces which is what are causing your shading atifacts - deleting the extra faces fixes it - problem is, there are thousands:

[image: Islands]

Given this, you will probably have to look at how all the "bundles" are instanced, to see if you can remove the "doubling" effect that way.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Also you can only really see the two that will be in front of the camera so it wont be that big of a deal.